# Одновременная сортировка массива слов и букв javascript методом sort

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Задание такое:
Дано предложение, в котором слова разделены запятой.
Нужно создать ассоциативный массив:
1. Cначала идут слова, собранные по увеличению длины и отсортированные по алфавиту с ключами а1, а2...
2. Потом числа (включая отрицательные и нецелые) по возрастанию суммы цифр с ключами n1, n2...
Пример: лес, бочка, 20, бык, крик, 3, --8, 9.6.5, -7-, 3.в, 8..0, -9, 567, 9.6, 90, 05, 1, вор, слово, ров, кров, 04, бак, брак, гора, 7.1, банк, бросок, ложка, шаблон, нож

Так вот сделал я это посредством разбития массива на два массива, массив цифр и массив слов, и далее отсортировав их по отдельности, записал их в ответ. 
(после получения значение из input я разбиваю значение на массив `var str = str.split(", ");`)
Можно ли как то сразу полученный массив(цифр и слов одновременно) из input отсортировать через sort?

---

```
 numArr.sort((a, b) => sumCount(a) - sumCount(b));
wordArr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b));
```

Comment: Можно через первый sort сгруппировать отдельно числа и слова, через второй sort сразу отсортировать массив. Но вариант с отдельными массивами легче и понятнее ( + гарантированно правильный ) - в случае с одним массивом, придется продумать - что будет на "границе" слов и чисел.